# Bootstrap 4 Carousel - Text Left / Image Right

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to figure if this design is possible with the Bootstrap 4 carousel.

[image]

Essentially i'm looking to make a slider like in the above image but I can't figure out if it's possible to have the text on the left and the image on the right with the arrows.

Is this possible?

Any help is much appreciated.

I just have the default Bootstrap 4 carousel code at the moment.

```html
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="..." alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you attempted anything to get the left/right layout?

Comment: I looked at this example: https://codepen.io/Hazard_Droid/pen/QXJxVZ I tried it out but it seemed very unresponsive and I wasn't sure on how to remedy that. I also tried using float left and right but again it was difficult to get it to act well responsively.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Bootstrap grid. For example 2 columns...

```
      <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
             <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <div class="row align-items-center">
                            <div class="col-md py-2">
                                <p> Text text text here. Text here, here, here, here is the text. Text here, here, here, here is the text. </p>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary">More here</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md py-2">
                                <img class="d-block img-fluid" src="..." alt="First slide">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        ...
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        ...
                    </div>
             </div>
      </div>
```

[Codeply demo](https://www.codeply.com/p/O6lLDUerrw)